# what is the best way to add DateTimePicker data to database

Tags: database, vb.net

Below is the code i am using for my bindings but is giving me an error and its to do with the datatimepicker as if i remove this and add a textbox i get no error!! So obviously its something i am doing, so what is the best way to get the data from the datatimepicker and insert it into the database and with that said, on form load what is the value i need to grab the new value from that row to the datatimepicker.

Insert code:

```
Private Sub AddOrder()
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblo(SDate, EDate)VALUES(?, ?);"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DTS.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DTE.Value
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

bindings:

```
DTS.DataBindings.Add("value", bsorder, "SDate")
    DTE.DataBindings.Add("value", bsorder, "EDate")
```

Is this the only way to do this? It gives me a error when i use this way, if i just use textboxes for adding time it works so its something to do with my way of doing this DataTimePicker,
Please help thanks!

Comment: Which line errors and what is the error?

Comment: what is the column type for those in the DB? A recent question showed many, many more columns; unless they are optional you need to specigy them too.  And, yes please dont keep the error a secret

Comment: When i add a order it works it adds to the database. but when i load search customer to view my added order it gives me this error: Databinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings. This is now leading back to my error on the other question that isnt answered. If i remove this whole datatimepicker and put it to textboxes i get no error in which is why it results back to this whole datatimepicker, is the above code correct?

Comment: All i have in search is: `Call UpdateBindingsOrder()
        bsorder.DataSource = dtorder
        bsorder.MoveFirst()
        BtnPrev.Enabled = (bsorder.Position > 0)
        BtnStart.Enabled = (bsorder.Position > 0)`
Basically when i add a order i call a reset method in which is makes everything null so textbox.text = "" etc making it go back to default so when i load search it will be nulled so by doing the above code it will restart the binding and bayum, i can search! This method works on my add customer nothings changes, apart from the date thing :/

Comment: @Plutonix i now get an error: Value of '01/01/0001 00:00:00' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'MinDate' and 'MaxDate'. Pointing at: bsorder.DataSource = dtorder when i add an order, The code in add button is: `Call Write2tableAddOrder()
                                        Call UpdateBindingsOrder()
                                        bsorder.DataSource = dtorder`

Comment: When my table is empty (Nothing in database) I get error: DataBinding cannot find a row in the list that is suitable for all bindings. on the line: bsorder.datasource etc but if i have data in the table and im adding another order i get the above message with the cannot find a row ..

Comment: I guess im on my own @Plutonix or?:/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when trying to databind to a DateTimePicker it didnt like the whole Value even though it is a valid property as there is no "Text" within this. Anyway, when i change it to:

```
DTS.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsorder, "SDate")
DTE.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsorder, "EDate")
```

My error/issue goes away! It use to be "Value" instead of text but some reason it likes text now Value. I dont have a detailed report as to why or how this works? I just trial and error it and worked a charm now!